# Unsigned int values

Tags: c, integer, unsigned

In this program, counter is declared with type `unsigned int`. Unsigned integer values are 0 or greater. All other variables are declared `int`. Those values will also only be a positive value. So why is each variable not declared as `unsigned int`?

[image]

Comment: You also don't need to declare all your vars at the top anymore. Even back in the day, you could so `unsigned int counter = 0;`, though. This program is overly wordy as a result.

Comment: WOW! Very helpful information and strong points. I did not think about the grading scale. I was assuming it would only be 0-100. Answered my question definitely! Thank you for your time!!

Comment: `counter = 1` and `while ( counter <= 10 )`?   Did a FORTRAN disciple write that textbook?

Comment: Note that the vote down is likely because you posted a picture of text. Generally, code should always be pasted as text, not as a picture. However, since this question included additional text and formatting besides code, it would have been more difficult to reproduce it faithfully.

Comment: Thank you! New User. I was not aware of that. It will not happen again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem specification does not stipulate that grade is greater than or equal to zero.

You may be familiar with grades from 0 to 100 or other non-negative scales, but that does not mean somebody else does not use a scale from −5 to +5. Some standardized test questions award −1 point for a wrong answer, 0 for no answer, and 3 for a correct answer so that, when there are four multiple-choice answers, random guessing has an average score of zero, but guessing after eliminating a known-wrong answer has a positive average score, so the test more accurately measures knowledge even if it is incomplete.

In general, one should not make assumptions about data that are not stated in the problem. Being aware of one’s own inherent assumptions and questioning them when a problem statement is incomplete is an important skill for designing software.

Further, even if the grade range is 0 to 100, both `unsigned int` and `int` cover that range, so there is little reason to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that I can see. I agree it would be better if they were all `unsigned`.

Comment: Thank you! Just making sure I was not crazy haha.